# regex search for < (random content) class (random content) class (random content) >?

Tags: html, regex

Right so basically,

I have some malformed tags, they have two `class` attributes, which is breaking things,

So I need to go through and find any tags that are like that,

My IDE has a regex search, but I don't know what I would put in it,

The regex needs to say, starts with `<` and has two instances of the word `class` before it hits a `>`

How would I write that regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this I guess:

```
<[^<>]*(\bclass\b[^<>]*){2,}>
```

Comment: perfect :) and you even have some epic looking smiley's in there too ;) will accept asap.

Comment: This allows the tag to start with class. Like this: <class something class="classname"> which is not correct I guess.

Comment: Well, for my purpose if the tag starts with <class then it is incorrect anyway ;)